# Use CDC and HID classes simultaneously in USB?

Tags: usb, mouse, hid, cdc

I'm new with USB.

I want to implement a pointing device on a PIC microcontroller.  USB will be used for communications between the pointing device and the host.

I would like to do the following:

1. Send deltas to the host's HID class driver, so the device can function as a simple mouse immediately after plug-in.
2. Send other data to the host using the CDC class for it to be post-processed by an application running on user space.

My main questions are:

- What is the best way to implement this? Should I define 2 distinct interfaces?
- What descriptors should I define?

I'm thinking of the following:

```
 Device descriptor
 Config descriptor

 Interface 0 descriptor
 Functional descriptors
 EP descriptor

 Interface 1 descriptor (CDC)
 EP descriptors

 Interface 2 descriptor (HID)
 EP descriptors
```

How should I define the "functional descriptors" that go after Interface 0 descriptor? Should I define interfaces 1 and 2 as slaves of interface 0?

Comment: You should implement a composite device.  It's probably a good idea to get an Arduino Leonardo and use the Arduino Mouse library to see how they do it.  It implements a CDC serial port and a mouse at the same time.  You can use `lsusb` on a Linux computer to list its descriptors in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must implement two distinct interface for two interface types.
You need to go through the CDC and HID specifications to understand the interface descriptors and (Endpoint descriptors).

I did not understand "slave interface" word. Did you mean alternate interface?
You do not need any alternate interfaces.

Example for multiple interfaces please refer to the image.

[image]

Thanks